# POST 400 (BAD REQUEST) React // Formik // MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, mongoose

I'm struggling to work out why I keep getting a POST 400 (BAD REQUEST) error on the code below. The API seems to be working fine.  I have built this form using Formik and I'm trying to save the email address to MongoDB.

Many thanks in advance if anyone can help.

```
import { useFormik } from "formik";
import styles from "../css/new.module.css";
import axios from "axios";

const AddTrader = () => {
  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      email: "",
    },
    onSubmit: (values) => {
      axios
        .post(`${process.env.ADDRESS}/api/notes`, values)
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    },
  });

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <div className={styles.wrapper}>
        <h1>List a trader</h1>

        <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
          <label htmlFor="email">Email Address</label>
          <input
            id="email"
            name="email"
            type="email"
            onChange={formik.handleChange}
            value={formik.values.email}
          />
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AddTrader;
```

Schema:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const TraderSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  email: String,
  created: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
});

module.exports = mongoose.models.Note || mongoose.model("Note", TraderSchema);
```

Comment: What does the request look like in the browser's developer tools network view?

Comment: @Christian Thanks for your reply, screenshot here -  https://ibb.co/8rhbBGN https://ibb.co/jD0Jqgs

Comment: Click on the row with the request and you can see the request and response in more detail. Specifically, the response tab might give you more useful info.
Also, what does your server code look like?

Comment: https://ibb.co/Rh2G0Dd

the request returns : {"success":false}

Comment: So do a `console.log(error)` in the catch before response is sent.
Also, the `dbConnect` is probably asynchronous so you should `await` it before handling any requests.

Comment: @Christian - thank you so much for explaining this to me. I was getting a E11000 Error due to using a colleciton with duplicate null fields. Much appricated!